# Finding if a specific value is in a given column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and tried to use the following:

```
pos = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'pred'])
pos.loc[1,'id'] = [4, 4, 4]
pos.loc[2,'id'] = [2, 3, 3]
list1 = [2, 3, 3]
list2 = [3, 2, 3]
print(pos)
print(list1 in pos['id'].values)
print(list2 in pos['id'].values)
```

It gives me the Error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)

Comment: This works in pandas 2.1 and returns `False`. Which version did you use? What is the expected output?

Comment: @mozway It doesn't work with pandas `2.2.1`.

Comment: I use google colab. Any ideas how it can be corrected? I expect True, False in the last two commands outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any()`:

```py
list1 = [2, 3, 3]
list2 = [3, 2, 3]

print(any(l == list1 for l in pos["id"]))
print(any(l == list2 for l in pos["id"]))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) to get a python object instead of a numpy array:

```
list1 in pos['id'].to_list()
# True

list2 in pos['id'].tolist()
# False
```

Intermediate:

```
pos['id'].tolist()
# [[4, 4, 4], [2, 3, 3]]
```